How to adjust the space between 'degree/job' and 'description' in moderncv banking style?
I want to use moderncv's banking style to create my CV.
The following figure is one of the \cventry items.
I am wondering if there's a way to change the space between 'degree/job'(e.g. M.S., institute of ...) and 'description'(e.g. - Advisor ...)? Because my description has two lines, it looks weird if the space are different between every line.

This is how I wrote it:
\cventry{Sep 2018 -- Jul 2020}{M.S.}{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX University}{Location}{Institute of XXXXXX}{
    - Advisor: XXXXXXX XXXXXX\newline{}
    - Thesis: Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    }

Thank you for your help!
